# Reference-counted object is used after it is released warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm getting the warning for the following code:

```
NSString *userMail = (__bridge NSString *) contactInfo;
CFRelease(contactInfo);

// Persist the user mail in NSUserDefaults
[[SettingsHelper sharedInstance] setUserMail:userMail];
```

After I release `contactInfo` I'm not referencing it anymore, so I don't really understand the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bridged cast transfers something into or out of ARC control, but it gives you a pointer that ARC assumes is retained somewhere else.

#### Alternative 1 (ugly)

If you use a normal `__bridge`, you can't release the object until you are done with it.

```
NSString *userMail = (__bridge NSString *) contactInfo;
[[SettingsHelper sharedInstance] setUserMail:userMail];
CFRelease(contactInfo);
```

#### Alternative 2 (nice)

If you use a `__bridge_transfer`, ARC will track it for you.

```
NSString *userMail = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) contactInfo;
[[SettingsHelper sharedInstance] setUserMail:userMail];
```

#### Summary

The `__bridge` cast should only be used for casting reference-counted types to non-reference-counted types.  For example, between `void *` and `NSString *`.  You need to use it to write callback functions in C, for example.

The `__bridge_transfer` cast will let you convert from one reference-counted type to another, such as `CFStringRef` to `NSString *`.

Answer (score 0):

userMail is just a reference to your contactInfo object. calling userMail is like calling contactInfo. Here you release contactInfo then try to set userMail(which is a reference to contactInfo) as the userMail of settingsHelper.

try this way,

```
NSString *userMail = (__bridge NSString *) contactInfo;

// Persist the user mail in NSUserDefaults
[[SettingsHelper sharedInstance] setUserMail:userMail];
CFRelease(contactInfo);
```